# How does JobSchedule persist jobs? When should I reschedule them?

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I'm currently working on an application that requires certain job to run on a very specific time no matter what happens - device restarts, local time is changed, app is updated and so on. That time is fetched from the server in terms of seconds. So, when I receive that value, I create a job with a code similar to this

```
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context, MyJobService.class);
JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(jobId, componentName);
builder.setMinimumLatency(secondsFromApi * 1000);
builder.setOverrideDeadline(secondsFromApi * 1000);
builder.setPersisted(true);
JobScheduler scheduler = context.getSystemService(JobScheduler.class);
scheduler.schedule(builder.build());
```

Everything works fine, even when I restart the device, the job is fired at expected time. However, things get messy when I change the device time manually before doing the restart. Imagine the situation that I've let say created a job to run in 120 seconds, then I went to device settings, changed the time back to several hours, and shut down the device. Then I waited for some time, that's greater than 120 seconds to make the condition even more extreme and I've turned on the device. Unfortunately the job won't run. If I didn't change the time and restarted the phone and waited for 5 minutes and turned it back on, the job would fire just about a minute after the boot, most probably when operating system completes it's mandatory actions and proceeds to executing pending jobs and finds mine and executes it.

Following the logic of the previous example, my assumption is that the JobScheduler doesn't actually count down the timer while the device is offline. Rather, when I try to shut down, it would most probably count how many milliseconds are there left for the job to be triggered, will record the time when the device is restarted and store that value. When I restart the device, it would fetch the current time and add the remaining milliseconds and reschedule the job. In this scenario, if the device time becomes different from the time when the job was initially scheduled, then after the restart the job will either fire too late (if the time was changed backwards) or too soon (if the time was changed to future).

So, to summarize there are several questions that arise from my obvervations

1. Is my logic correct?
2. If yes, does this mean that I should create a boot listener and re-fetch the
   seconds from the API after device reboots to make sure the job will
   fire at correct time no matter how the user change the clock?
3. Are there other occasions that I should do a re-scheduling? I
   noticed in some threads, that when app is updated jobs are
   discarded. So, most probably I need to do a reschedule at that case
   as well? Are there other reasons why I'd need to do a rescheduling?

Comment: Point 2 and 3, right assumptions. After an update, you may need to update jobs too, faced same in firebase job dispatcher. For point 1: ACTION_TIME_CHANGED Intent fire an broadcast when the user changed time from settings then you can do whatever.

Comment: @notTdar thanks for the reply.  I was doing some tests, and seems my assumptions are validated as well. I tried both putting clock back and forward. In back scenario, the job is not executed after restart, rather it's delayed. When putting the clock forward, the job would execute right after the boot - resulting in  early execution. It seems that we can not trust setPersisted when device time is subject to a change.

Comment: well, it's kinda like that but a lot of factors are there. An alternative to your case, if jobs to be executed precisely whether your change the system clock or not, go for fb remote config or fcm for a/b type values.based on that you could decide jobs to schedule now or not

Comment: @notTdar We are going to have fcm as well, unfortunately there's a reason why we need to schedule it locally, most of the users are going to be offline. And we need to make some measures to make sure the action is executed at the time we expect.

Comment: offline, so Doze mode will be the top priority. You can use AlarmManager where setExactWhileIdle to bypass Doze. I'd suggest you use both combinations, online (fb) and offline(am) and prompt for whitelisting the app.

Comment: @notTdar Yes I agree with you, thanks a lot. I used JobScheduler for it's reboot persistence capabilities in the first place. As it's no longer a valid point and in any case I'll need to do a rescheduling, then yes, AlarmManager with setExactWhileIdle is the best approach.

Comment: @notTdar You're more than welcome to write an answer to this question combining comments from above, and I'll be more than happy marking it as an answer.